# NODE JS Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to learn puppeteer and I wanted to scrape the StockX web page at https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha.

I wanted to scrape the title of the shoe at first such as "Dior B713 CACTUS JACK".

I tried to use : await document.querySelector to scrape the title but the page freezes and displays this error Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText'). Knowing that in the console the information is well returned.

I tried to use the exact CSS selector of the Google development tools, but without success. I have tried several combinations of CSS selectors, but I am still not able to extract the title I want.

```
 const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);
        // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
        const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let demandes = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-j7qwjs > div > h1').innerText;
            return demandes;
          })
          console.log(demandes);
          await browser

    }
}

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

Comment: You're just trying to get the product name? Adding a comment isn't enough to wait for an element, you have to call `page.waitForSelector()` first--but it'll probably time out unless you click through the size and cookie banners. You can get the property from the static HTML with or without Puppeteer--I'd just do that. `await page.title()`. It's also in the twitter card and JSON payload statically. Much easier than messing with banners and the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, here is a new error : ReferenceError: demandes is not defined

I don't understand, can you please help me?

Comment: `console.log(result)`. `demandes` is only defined in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's no clear need to work with the DOM here at all, or Puppeteer for that matter, just to retrieve the product name, which is available in a few different places in the static HTML. Search `view-source:https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha` by "Dior B713 CACTUS JACK" to see all occurrences. The easiest to get appears to be the page title or twitter:title meta tag.

With Cheerio and Node 18 (for native `fetch`; install `node-fetch` if you're on an older Node):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

fetch("https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    console.log($('meta[property="twitter:title"]').attr("content"));

    // or:
    console.log($("title").text());
  })
;
```

Puppeteer:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^15.4.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  const url = "https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

  const title = await page.$eval(
    'meta[property="twitter:title"]',
    el => el.getAttribute("content")
  );
  console.log(title);

  // or:
  console.log(await page.title());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output:

```
Dior B713 CACTUS JACK Mocha
Dior B713 CACTUS JACK Mocha - 3SN281ZNV_H967StockX LogoStockX Logo
```